# How Should use external javascript library in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's wrong in my initialization, when I trying to use external javascript library in jquery
and I want to get a custom value from my pages and then manipulate that value by using external javascript plugin and then return back new value(or replace with old value),
below is my code:

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="external-library.js"></script>
  <script>
  var OldValue;
  var NewValue;
  OldValue = $(".raw-Data").html();
  NewValue = new External-function(OldValue);

  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".result").text(NewValue);
  });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="raw-Data">1318781876406</div>
  <div class="result"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

When I add my `<script>` section in my document `<head>` section like above code all things works correctly and I haven't any problem,
But the problem arise when I want to add `<script>` section in end of document before closing `<body>` tag
because Drupal CMS initializing javascript library in bottom of document.

```
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
  <div class="raw-Data">1318781876406</div>
  <div class="result"></div>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="External-Library.js"></script>
  <script>
  var OldValue;
  var NewValue;

  $(document).ready(function() {
  OldValue = $(".raw-Data").html();
  NewValue = new ExternalFunction(OldValue);
  $(".result").text(NewValue);
  });
  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I want to know what's the correct and compacted method to do this.

Thanks for any help or suggestion.

Comment: make `var Old-Value;
  var New-Value;` to `var oldValue; var newValue` and dont use `-` in function names, that wont work

Comment: Your trying to read from the HTML `Old-Value = $(".raw-Data").html();` before the document is ready. Move this line into `$(document).ready(`

Comment: @Liam: Thank you so much, I move `OldValue = $(".raw-Data").html();` to `$(document).ready(` section but nothing changed.

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani as Liam said the line `OldValue = $(".raw-Data").html();` wont work. You're looking for class `row-Data` but it does not exists yet. Take that line of code into your `ready` function and it should work

Comment: @MojtabaReyhani here https://jsfiddle.net/2qytc967/2/

Comment: @Nitro.de: I move `OldValue = $(".raw-Data").html();` to `$(document).ready(` section but nothing changed, I assume this problem should comes from external library because when I put my `<script>` section in my document `<head>` section like in question all things works correctly and I haven't any problem,

Answer (score 0):

JS variable names / function cannot contain `-` sign.

the common naming convention used by javascript is **camelCase**

so that `New-Value` should become `newValue`
and `External-Function` should change to `externalFunction`

see javascript variable naming convention on w3schools for more information :

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp

Comment: Thank you so much, I change my variable names but nothing changed.